# Não consigo pegar informações da minha API através de aplicativo android

Tags: php, android, sql, json

Criei uma API web com o código:

```
 <?php

    header('Content-type: Application/JSON');

    include("../Classes/conexao.php");

    if($_SESSION['conectado'] == false){
        echo json_encode("Sem resposta do servidor");
    }else{

        $usuario = $_REQUEST['usuario'];
        $senha = $_REQUEST['senha'];

        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM estabelecimento WHERE cpf_responsavel = '$usuario' AND senha = '$senha';";
        $resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta) or die($mysqli->error);

        $n = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

        for ($i=0; $i < $n; $i++) { 
            $dados[] = $resultado->fetch_assoc();       
        }

        echo json_encode((object)$dados, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    }

?>
```

Que retorna o seguinte json:

```
 {
    "0": {
        "id": "",
        "cnpj": "",
        "cpf_responsavel": "",
        "url_logo": "http",
        "senha": "",
        "especialidade": "",
        "razao_social": "",
        "avaliacao": ""
    }
}
```

Criei tbm um aplicativo android para consumir essa API usando o retrofit. O problema é que o app consegue se conectar com o serviço só que não consigo faze-lo salvar nenhum dos dados expressos no json.

Comment: Você liberou o [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS) na sua api?

Comment: Sou iniciante. Não tenho certeza.

Comment: Habilitei e não funcionou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que não esteja conseguindo salvar porque o array que está transformando em json é um array multidimensional. Então ele gera os índices em seu JSON que acredito ser desnecessário.

Faça o seguinte passo e veja se o problema será resolvido.

Em seu código php, ao invés de gerar um array associativo dos resultados da consulta, gere um objeto para cada linha.

```
for ($i=0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    $dados[] = $resultado->fetch_object();
}

 echo json_encode($dados, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

> Veja que não estou convertendo todo o array para objeto mas sim cada
>   linha retornada da consulta ao banco.

Comment: Essa foi a saída:

[
    {
        "id": "  ",
        "cnpj": "    ",
        "cpf_responsavel": "  ",
        "url_logo": "  ",
        "senha": "  ",
        "especialidade": "  ",
        "razao_social": "  ",
        "avaliacao": "  "
    }
]

Comment: Só que ainda sim o app não consegue consumir os dados

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver.
Eu estou utilizando no android a biblioteca retrofit2 que exige um formatação específica de json. Para chegar em tal formatação eu montei o objeto json manualmente:

```
$json = [
            "Estabelecimento"  => [
                    "id" => "".$dados['id']."",
                    "cnpj" => "".$dados['cnpj']."",
                    "cpf_responsavel" => "".$dados['cpf_responsavel']."",
                    "url_logo" => "".$dados['url_logo']."",
                    "senha" => "".$dados['senha']."",
                    "especialidade" => "".$dados['especialidade']."",
                    "razao_social" => "".$dados['razao_social']."",
                    "avaliacao" => "".$dados['avaliacao'].""]
            ];


        echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Obteve essa saída:

```
{
"Estabelecimento": {
    "id": "700",
    "cnpj": "555",
    "cpf_responsavel": "799",
    "url_logo": "http",
    "senha": "123",
    "especialidade": "nada",
    "razao_social": "JV",
    "avaliacao": "5"
}
```

}

Assim o app conseguiu resgatar todos os dados